reserve disk space for a huge file
I am working on an encryption system, which in theory should support incredibly huge files (50GB and more). Encryption algorithm is a bit complex and it requires writing to an output file in a non-contiguous way, meaning all file space has to be accessible before writing any data to it.
Working with memory is out of option, since most people are not gonna have enough memory. I would need to write straight to a file, hence reserve disk space instead.
I am aware of std::filesystem::resize_file, but honestly I am not sure how it works. Does it actually reserve disk space or does it reserve memory? If it reserves disk space, is it capable of non-contiguous reservation? Because disk space is usually very fragmented and contiguous reservation of (let's say) 50GB most likely not gonna be allowed even when disk has way more free space.

It'll be up to your filesystem how the file is allocated, it's unlikely to be fully contiguous

std::filesystem::resize_file changes the actual size on disk (filling it with some unspecified data). But there's no guarantee how the file is physically stored (it's up to the OS/filesystem). You can still use seekg or similar to write to it in a non-contiguous way.

@wohlstad you sure resizing alone writes nonsensical data to a disk? Unnecessary operation and poor performance. I would fill all this space manually anyways

The documentation says: "the file size is increased and the new area appears as if zero-filled". On Windows I verified that it fills it with actual zeros. Which OS are you using ?

@wohlstad windows as well. the documentation should say "new area is literally filled with zeros" then, instead of giving vague hints. I wonder whether there's a way to simply reserve disk space without performing other unnecessary operations

The documentation quote I wrote is from cppreference, not Windows specific (so it makes sense it gives some freedom to the implementation). Maybe there's some Windows-specific API to do what you need. You can try SetFileValidData. Also some answers here might help.

Why does it matter if zeros are actually written to the disk or not?  The file appears to be zero-filled.  How that's achieved is up to the implementation (i.e. it looks like libstdc++ uses ftruncate64 internally).

@MilesBudnek in my case reserving disk space is all I need, filling it up is a superfluous operation

Does this answer your question? How do you pre-allocate space for a file in C/C++ on Windows?

@BoP: Your proposed duplicate question is helpful, but not a duplicate, because the proposed duplicate question asks specifically about the Microsoft Windows platform, whereas the question at hand asks about std::filesystem in general (which is platform-independant, and did not yet exist when the linked question was asked).

If this is on Linux, you can use the fallocate(2) or posix_fallocate(3).
std::filesystem::resize_file seems to be using truncate(2), which can lead to sparse files on most filesystems. i.e., it does not reserve actual disk space, but just increases the file's apparent size.
